# Postgresql version mismatch between pgAdmin and console

Tags: postgresql

I had running PostgreSQL version 10 on IOS and then I installed version 13.1. Now, when I run pgAdmin, I can still see the databases I created for version 10, and pgAdmin reports the server as version 10. Nevertheless, command `pg_config --version` in console returns `PostgreSQL 13.1`. I don't know how to sync pgAdmin with the new version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Presumably the two versions are installed side by side on different ports. If using Debian/Ubuntu, this is normal. See [pg_lsclusters](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/postgresql-common/pg_lsclusters.1.en.html) and [pg_upgradecluster](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/postgresql-common/pg_upgradecluster.1.en.html)

Comment: @DanielVérité I missed to point that my OS is IOS, and there is not such thing as pg_clusters in my postgres dirs. Do I have to install it?